# Let $A=\{1,2,3,...,2^n\}$. Consider the greatest odd factor of each element of A and add them...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $A=\{1,2,3,...,2^n\}$. Consider the greatest odd factor (not necessarily prime) of each element of A and add them. What does this sum equal?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you are given some Big Number, do you know how to compute its greatest odd factor by removing some powers of $2$?

Comment: No, I dont know how to.

Comment: For odd $k$, the largest odd factor is just $k$. For even $k$, the largest odd factor is $k$ with the powers of $2$ removed.

Comment: @problembuster Really? Have you tried actually writing out any examples and seeing if there's a pattern? What's the largest odd factor of $14$? Of $28$? Of $56$ or $98$?

Comment: Yes, I know how to do that, what I mean is that I dont know how to count them up to $2^n$.

Answer (score 5):

For positive integer $k$, let $L(k)$ be the largest odd factor of $k$. Then we have:

$L(k) = L(k/2)$ if $k$ is even, and $L(k) = k$ if $k$ is odd.

We compute:

$$S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{2^n} L(k)$$

$$S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}} L(2k)  + \sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}} L(2k-1)$$

$$S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}} L(2k)  + \sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}} (2k-1)$$

$$S(n) = (\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}} L(2k))  + 4^{n-1}$$

$$S(n) = (\sum_{k=1}^{2^{n-1}} L(k))  + 4^{n-1}$$

$$S(n) = S(n-1)  + 4^{n-1}$$

$$S(n) = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n} 4^{k-1} = \frac{4^{n}+2}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the first $m$ odd numbers is $1+3+5+7+\cdots+(2m-1)=m^2$.

Excluding $2^n$, we sum the first $2^{n-1}$ odd numbers, then the first $2^{n-2}$ odd numbers under the guise of their doubles, then the first $2^{n-3}$ odd numbers under the guise of their quadruples, etc.

> For example, when $n=3$
>   $$
> \color{#0000F0}{1}+\color{#00A000}{2}+\color{#0000F0}{3}+\color{#C00000}{4}+\color{#0000F0}{5}+\color{#00A000}{6}+\color{#0000F0}{7}+8\\
> \color{#0000F0}{16}+\color{#00A000}{4}+\color{#C00000}{1}+1=22
> $$
>   The first $2^{n-1}$ odd numbers are in blue, the doubles of the first $2^{n-2}$ odd numbers are in green, the quadruples of the first $2^{n-3}$ odd numbers are in red. This coloring excludes $2^n$.
>
> For example, when $n=4$
>   $$
> \color{#0000F0}{1}+\color{#00A000}{2}+\color{#0000F0}{3}+\color{#C00000}{4}+\color{#0000F0}{5}+\color{#00A000}{6}+\color{#0000F0}{7}+\color{#F08030}{8}+\color{#0000F0}{9}+\color{#00A000}{10}+\color{#0000F0}{11}+\color{#C00000}{12}+\color{#0000F0}{13}+\color{#00A000}{14}+\color{#0000F0}{15}+16\\
> \color{#0000F0}{64}+\color{#00A000}{16}+\color{#C00000}{4}+\color{#F08030}{1}+1=86
> $$
>   The first $2^{n-1}$ odd numbers are in blue, the doubles of the first $2^{n-2}$ odd numbers are in green, the quadruples of the first $2^{n-3}$ odd numbers are in red, the octuples of the first $2^{n-4}$ odd numbers are in orange. This coloring excludes $2^n$.

Excluding the term for $2^n$, we get
$$
\left(2^{n-1}\right)^2+\left(2^{n-2}\right)^2+\left(2^{n-3}\right)^2+\dots+1=\frac{4^n-1}{4-1}
$$
Including the term for $2^n$, which adds $1$, the final sum is
$$
\frac{4^n-1}{3}+1=\frac{4^n+2}{3}
$$